# Unable to fetch data from table which has one to one mapping in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

Below is my base table

```
package com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.abc.xyz.casa.enums.AccountStatus;
import com.abc.xyz.domain.AbstractAuditableDomainEntity;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "casa_account_master")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@IdClass(DemandDepositEntityKey.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemandDepositAccountEntity extends AbstractAuditableDomainEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name="account_title")
    private String accountTitle;

    @Column(name="system_status")
    private String systemStatus;

    @Column(name="account_opening_posting_date")
    private Date accountOpeningPostingDate;

    @Column(name="account_opening_value_date")
    private Date accountOpeningValueDate;

    @Column(name="user_defined_status")
    private String userDefinedStatus;

    @Column(name="currency_code")
    private String currencyCode;

    @Column(name = "bank_code")
    private String bankCode;

    @Column(name = "branch_code")
    private String branchCode;

    @Column(name = "branch_name")
    private String branchName;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name="business_unit")
    private String businessUnit;

    @Column(name="market_entity")
    private String marketEntity;

    @Column(name="status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountStatus accountStatus;

    @Column(name="version_no")
    private String versionNo;

    @Column(name="relationship_officer")
    private String relationshipOfficer;

    @Column(name="offer_code")
    private String offerCode;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    @Embedded
    private AdditionalFeaturesEntity additionalFeatures;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    @Embedded
    private DefaultFeaturesEntity defaultFeatures;

    @Column(name="linked_mobilenumber_pk")
    private String linkedMobileNumberPK;

    @Column(name="linked_address_pk")
    private String linkedAddressPK;

}
```

my EntityKey class, DemandDepositEntityKey.java

```
package com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts;

import com.abc.xyz.domain.AbstractDomainKey;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="casa_account_master")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor

public class DemandDepositEntityKey extends AbstractDomainKey implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;

    @Override
    public String keyAsString() {
        return accountId;
    }
}
```

Below are my 2 class which are mapped as one to one in DemandDepositAccountEntity.java.
They are AdditionalFeaturesEntity.java and DefaultFeaturesEntity.java

```
package com.abc.xyzcasa.domain.entity.accounts;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "casa_additional_features")
public class AdditionalFeaturesEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;
    @Column (name = "sweep_in")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean sweepIn;
    @Column(name = "cheque_book")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean chequeBook;
    @Column(name = "periodic_credit")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean periodicCredit;
    @Column(name = "passbook")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean passbook;
    @Column(name = "debit_card")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean debitCard;
    @Column(name = "internet_banking")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean internetBanking;
    @Column(name = "atm")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean atm;
    @Column(name = "phone_banking")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean phoneBanking;
    @Column(name = "mobile_banking")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean mobileBanking;
    @Column(name = "branch_banking")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean branchBanking;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "additionalFeatures")
    private DemandDepositAccountEntity demandDepositAccountEntity;
}
```

```
package com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "casa_default_features")
public class DefaultFeaturesEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;
    @Column (name = "over_draft")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean overDraft;
    @Column(name = "over_line")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean overLine;
    @Column(name = "tod")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean tod;
    @Column(name = "debit_balance_allowed")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean debitBalanceAllowed;
    @Column(name = "adv_against_unclear_funds")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean advAgainstUnclearFunds;
    @Column(name = "principal_offset")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean principalOffset;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "defaultFeatures")
    private DemandDepositAccountEntity demandDepositAccountEntity;
}
```

my repository class

```
package com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.repository;

import com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts.DemandDepositAccountEntity;
import com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts.DemandDepositEntityKey;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface IDemandDepositRepository extends IAbstractRepository<DemandDepositAccountEntity, DemandDepositEntityKey> {

    public Optional<DemandDepositAccountEntity> findById(DemandDepositEntityKey demandDepositEntityKey);
    
    
    @Query(name = "select * from idgc_casa_account_master where account_id = ?0",nativeQuery = true)
    public  DemandDepositAccountEntity findByAccountId(String accountId);
}
```

snippet of code where i am trying to fetch data

```
    public DemandDepositAccountEntity findByAccountId(String accountId) {
        DemandDepositAccountEntity demandDepositAccountEntity = null;
        try {
=            DemandDepositEntityKey demandDepositEntityKey = new DemandDepositEntityKey();
            demandDepositEntityKey.setAccountId(accountId);
            Optional<DemandDepositAccountEntity> demandDepositAccountEntityOptional = accountsRepository.findById(demandDepositEntityKey);
            if(demandDepositAccountEntityOptional.isPresent()){
                demandDepositAccountEntity = demandDepositAccountEntityOptional.get();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in getAllHistoryByAccountId", e);
            ExceptionUtil.handleException(DATA_ACCESS_ERROR);
        }
        return demandDepositAccountEntity;
    }
```

Error that we get in console

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts.DefaultFeaturesEntity. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class com.abc.xyz.casa.domain.entity.accounts.DemandDepositEntityKey